Display Widget with animation from AppBar and gray out rest of screen
I am interested in having a similar animation as the one below, what are possible approaches I can take.

The best solution I have so is to do a cross fade animation, then set some state variable, to gray out the rest of the screen. I wonder if there is a better solution.

Try this code
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimatedWidgetOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimatedWidgetOverlayState createState() => _AnimatedWidgetOverlayState();
}

class _AnimatedWidgetOverlayState extends State<AnimatedWidgetOverlay>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation<double> _animation;

  bool _isVisible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );
    _animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Curves.easeInExpo,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _toggleVisibility() {
    setState(() {
      _isVisible = !_isVisible;
      if (_isVisible) {
        _animationController.forward();
      } else {
        _animationController.reverse();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Animated Widget Overlay'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
            onPressed: _toggleVisibility,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          // Content of the main screen
          const Center(
            child: Text('Main Content'),
          ),
          // Backdrop Filter to gray out the rest of the screen
          if (_isVisible)
            BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              ),
            ),
          // Animated container to display over the main content
          Positioned.fill(
            child: AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: _animation,
              builder: (context, child) {
                return Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Opacity(
                    opacity: _animation.value,
                    child: Transform.translate(
                      offset: Offset(0, 100.0 * (-1 + _animation.value)),
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: 200,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Animated Widget',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

